# Single Node Cluster in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

Please let me know if its possible to setup a single node cluster using Azure Synapse Spark pool, i don't want any executor / worker nodes for my requirement .

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum number of nodes in a synapse cluster is 3.

Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-autoscale

[image: cluster]